# Do we really need email confirmation?

Tags: usability

I've gotten into a habit of using the standard register->send activation email->activate account process for every site that supports user authentication and free registration without  questioning if I really need this.

What are your thoughts on this? If I have captcha on the registration form is the email confirmation process really necessary?

EDIT:

OK, so the general consensus seems to be that by getting the users to confirm the email they entered I'll keep them away from putting someone else's email in there.
What about when I let users edit their profile/settings and they enter another email?
If I need to keep them away from entering other people's addresses then I'd need to confirm that email address (by temporarily deactivating their accoun)t every time they change it.

Comment: I think that Captcha alone is enough, but depending on your project and your RIVALS that have a website with the same purpose as yours, you should consider Captcha + Email Activation with no doubt.

Comment: I was considering going without the email confirmation and just using recaptcha but I ran into the problem of users making multiple fake accounts for certain benefits. For example on SO I may make 100 fake accounts and upvote everything i post however email confirm makes it too annoying, cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Captcha+activation prevents bots AND spoofed people

Well basically it is since each part prevents one problematic scenario:

- Captcha prevents (if you use strong captcha like reCaptcha) bots from registering new users
- Email activation prevents people from registering other people (by their email address)

I guess this is a valid everyday pattern for registration that's widely acknowledged by IT community.

**EDIT**
Yes. When you want to prevent users from changing their email address, you'd have to repeat email activation procedure to make it robust.
But you don't have to deactivate their account while doing it. All you have to do is having a pending email-change email activation active. If it gets activated, you change email address at that point (not when they change it), otherwise the old one is still used.

Comment: Your summary is a little unclear - email validation doesn't prevent bots. Captcha does. EV prevents identity theft (at the most basic level). Not sure what a "fake person" is...

Comment: @Rex: a fake person is a FAKE person. Someone that claims they're someone they're not. A fake Bill Gates would be some John Doe that registered with billg@microsoft.com email address.

Comment: @Robert Generally "fake person" means a person who does not exist. A better word for what you're describing might be something like "impersonation" or "identity theft".

Answer (score 6):

If you don't confirm an e-mail, you're supposing that the user registering that service owns that email account. How can you start sending a lot of system e-mails, reset passwords and etc to a person that has nothing to do with your system? I would be really pissed of if it was my e-mail.

Another scenario: what if the register mispelled his e-mail when registering? Suppose he doesn't check his "account settins" in your application, doesn't change his email, and needs to reset his password. If the e-mail is registered in a wrong way, it's your fault for not checking it before.

Of course, I'm just saying this to services that would REALLY demand an account to be created. Avoid the [login barrier](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000881.html) when possible, or use openid when your service isn't so critical.

Answer (score 5):

You should give serious consideration to supporting OpenID.  http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/

The key benefit for OpenID is that it reduces the complexity for your **user**.  There is no reason to force people to remember login credentials for hundreds of sites when a viable alternative exists.  There is no worldwide netizen database - and there likely never will be - but OpenID simplifies the situation greatly.

I know that as a user I found the registration process for Stack Overflow to be painless and easy.  I wish more sites used OpenID.

Comment: OpenID may be suitable for IT people (being the same reason why it's used here on SO), but regular internet users probably won't be able to make use of it. They may easily get confused.

Comment: ... same as tags. These work well on SO, but wouldn't in a non-IT community.

Comment: I have found OpenID to be a true pain coming through Wordpress.  I would not even *consider* imposing this on my users.

Comment: at some point, "non-IT people" didn't have passwords, or emails, or captchas, but they've managed to learn to cope with those.  They'll adapt.  They're just slower than us superior beings.

Comment: @Will & @rmeador: I agree they do get used to it. But your service may die before they acquire such knowledge. If you want to sell your service NOW, you have to think of your users what they are capable NOW not in the (near) future...

Comment: A few days ago I would've said that OpenID can be confusing for the average user.  But after seeing the most incredibly simple implementation of it in the DotNetOpenID project and the beauty of OpenID 2.0, I've become a much bigger fan of OpenID overall.  You can now register without typing in an OpenID address, but by clicking a Google or Yahoo login button instead. In fact I'm adding a login system to my site with nothing but OpenID just because of how awesomely simple it has become.

Answer (score 4):

It's the lowest-level attempt at **identity validation**. It encourages users to re-use the same account when they return (by having a common, shared identifier you and they can use to reconnect), and it prevents impersonation, because it requires access to the claimed identity as proof.

It's not perfect, but something by definition works infinitely better than nothing.

If identity doesn't matter on your site (e.g. your service is throwaway after each use) then you don't need email activation. Otherwise, you probably want it.

Comment: or better said: why would a "throwaway after each use" site even have user registration?

Comment: @Robert you're right, it wouldn't be a registration in that sense. But it might still expect name, contact info, etc. which is a kind of registration.

Comment: @Robert I don't think he meant "after each use" in an absolute sense. For example reddit.com doesn't use email confirmation so it can let users create throwaway accounts more easily (see the IAMA or GoneWild subreddits and you'll see why)

Answer (score 4):

On my site, I let users sign-up and do everything non-public until they confirm their email address. Because I run a gaming website, it means users can earn medals, post scores, just not post in the forum or post comments in the blog until they verify their email address.

I find it works pretty well. I have 16,000 registered users.

Answer (score 3):

I find it both unnecessary and annoying.  If I can, I avoid doing this.

However, I do do this if 1) email will be sent by the program, so I can test if the email address is valid, or 2) this is a very large, public-facing website, in which case I want to filter out as many potential problems as possible.

Answer (score 2):

For most basic sites, I don't bother with either.  Both email activation and captcha are relatively easy for dedicated spammers to bypass and overcome and do little but cause an annoyance to most of the users, driving away at least a certain percentage who might have otherwise signed up.  I've found in my experience, focusing more on spam filters for member posted content has a better ROI overall.

For sites with more serious content, you'll typically have more serious users.  In cases like that, I'll throw everything I've reasonably got available at it to counter the spam.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful when an email is sent for confirmation. This makes sure that I am the one who has registered with that email address.

Even with captcha you can register someone else email address although he may or may not approve that confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to need e-mail confirmation to confirm *identity*, not to send useful content by e-mail. But e-mail confirmation is only one means to an end. You may consider others, preferablly less intrusive ones.

Generally you can check something that

- you are (e.g. fingerprint, iris scan)
- you have (e.g. token, creditcard, key, **access to an e-mail account**)
- you know (e.g. PIN, password, your mom's weight, name of your favorite deceased pet, the optimistic length of your most private bodyparts measured in inches)

Also, you can delegate the check to others; the creditcard company, phone company, someone's friends.

> **Example:** GoogleMail could not ask
>   for a confirmation e-mail address
>   upon creation of your GMail account.
>   Instead, the early adopters had a limited supply of
>   "invites" to share with friends.

So - unless you actually need me to receive information you'd e-mail, which I generally hate anyway - you might be inclined to resort to more creative/fun means.